# Вывод элементов массива у которых ключ - число с плавающей точкой

Tags: javascript, массивы, join

Создаю массив, добавляю элементы, мне необходимо иметь в ключе число с плавающей точкой, когда пытаюсь вывести все элементы в одну строку через join - элементы, ключ которых НЕ целое число - пропускаются. Как решить проблему?

```
var arr = [];

arr[1] = "ключ 1";
arr[0.3] = "ключ 0.3";
arr[7] = "ключ 7";

    console.log(players.join(' ')); //console: ключ 1  ключ 7
```

Comment: Используйте объект вместо массива. В массиве ключи должны быть целочисленными, упорядоченными и, в идеале, без пропусков.

Comment: @smellyshoved не подскажете, как вывести все элементы объекта в одну строку?

Comment: Если вам нужно просто вывести в строку все элементы, то зачем вообще заморачиваться с ключами? Немного не понятен ваш use case

Comment: `Object.values(arr).join(' ')`

Comment: Расскажите лучше что за задачу вы пытаетесь решить с помощью таких ключей?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, так... Можно в обычный массив записать нужные вам числа.

```js
var arr = [];

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 0.3;
arr[2] = 7;

console.log( 'Ключ: ' + arr.join(', Ключ: ') );
```

Или, использовать обычный объект:

```js
var obj = {
  '1'  : 'Ключ 1',
  '0.3': 'Ключ 0.3',
  '7'  : 'Ключ 7'
}

console.log( Object.values( obj ) );
console.log( Object.values( obj ).join(' ') );

console.log( Object.keys( obj ) );
```